# Swift: Iterating, comparing and updating Sets inside Array

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, set

My goal is iterate through the array and find the sets that contains even one element in common. If this is true need to union this sets into one with elements from both sets. In my example I have two sets inside array that contains "Mars", in expected output should be array with three set inside and one of this sets should contain all elements from sets where was "Mars".

```
var dataArray = [
    Set.init(arrayLiteral: "Andromeda", "Milky Way", "Alpha Centauri"),
    Set.init(arrayLiteral: "Mars", "Earth", "Venus"),
    Set.init(arrayLiteral: "W Persei", "AZ Cygni", "Wezen"),
    Set.init(arrayLiteral: "Saturn", "Neptune", "Mars"),
]
```

I tried my best to achieve it with next logic:

```
dataArray.forEach { dataSet in
    dataArray.forEach { checkingSet in
        if !dataSet.isDisjoint(with: checkingSet) && dataSet != checkingSet {
            let _tempSet = dataSet.union(checkingSet)
            dataArray.filter { $0 != dataSet }
            dataArray.append(_tempSet)
        }
    }
}
```

But result isn't satisfy me because I still have more than three sets inside array and doing two ForEach statement through the same array not is good code. Is it possible to achieve described result with one loop only and got expected output with lower O(n)?

Expected output:

```
[Set(["Milky Way", "Alpha Centauri", "Andromeda"]), 
 Set(["W Persei", "Wezen", "AZ Cygni"]), 
 Set(["Mars", "Neptune", "Saturn", "Venus", "Earth"])]
```

Comment: If you have `[Set(["A", B"]), Set(["B", "C"]), Set(["C", "D"])`, in the end it should be `[Set(["A", "B", "C", "D"])]`, right? Ie, you might need a while loop? With your current sample and code, I got 7 sets in `dataArray` in the end.

Comment: Right, in your example I need exactly this output. Can you describe in more details what kind of condition should be in a while loop? My current code example doesn't satisfy requirement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice brain teaser, this is what I came up with, might not be the most efficient or make most use of Swift, but it should be O(n)? Also should works with the case Larme asked in the comment.

```
var dataArray = 
[
    Set.init(arrayLiteral: "Andromeda", "Milky Way", "Alpha Centauri"),
    Set.init(arrayLiteral: "Mars", "Earth", "Venus"),
    Set.init(arrayLiteral: "W Persei", "AZ Cygni", "Wezen"),
    Set.init(arrayLiteral: "Saturn", "Neptune", "Mars"),
    Set(["A", "B"]), 
    Set(["B", "C"]), 
    Set(["C", "D"])
]

var dict = [String:Int]()
var resultDict = [Int:Set<String>]() // Tried to use array it might have crash when replacing, might need some more checks if wanted to.
for (index, value) in dataArray.enumerated() {
    var matchedIndex: Int?
    for text in value {
        if let savedIndex = dict[text] {
            // found duplicated
            matchedIndex = savedIndex
            break
        }
    }
    if let matchedIndex = matchedIndex {
        let match = dataArray[matchedIndex].union(value)
        resultDict[matchedIndex] = match
        value.forEach({ dict[$0] = matchedIndex })
    } else {
        resultDict[index] = value
        value.forEach({ dict[$0] = index })
    }
}
print(resultDict.values)
/// [Set(["Alpha Centauri", "Andromeda", "Milky Way"]), Set(["Earth", "Neptune", "Venus", "Mars", "Saturn"]), Set(["AZ Cygni", "Wezen", "W Persei"]), Set(["B", "A", "D", "C"])]]
```

Comment: wow, great answer, output result exactly that it should be! I'm not pro in algorithms and in my humble opinion the fastest way iterate through all elements in array is O(n), but I can be wrong... If you don't mind I will keep question with no accepted answer for motivating people add more solutions

Comment: As long as can avoided double dataArray iteration then it should be good enough, I also think the most optimized in this case is O(n).